# How do I edit the HTML in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift2

I have a UIWebView that loads HTML. How do I access those HTML elements and change them?

I want to do something like: `webView.getHTMLElement(id: main-title).value = "New title"`

Comment: have you tried this: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-1/

Answer (score 6):

If you want to edit it in a form, this is how you can do it:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   NSString *evaluate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.form1.main-title.value='%@';", @"New title"];
   [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:evaluate];
}
```

Or if not in a form, maybe this (untested):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   NSString *evaluate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('main-title').value='%@';", @"New title"];
   [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:evaluate];
}
```

Note! I assume it is an editable field that you want to change. Otherwise you are talking about parsing and that concept works like this:

```
    static BOOL firstLoad = YES;

    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        if (firstLoad) {
            firstLoad = NO;
            NSString *html = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
            //Edit html here, by parsing or similar.
            [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
        }
    }
```

You can read more about parsing here: [Objective-C html parser](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser)

Answer (score 1):

First look at this post --> [Getting the HTML source code of a loaded UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167254/getting-the-html-source-code-of-a-loaded-uiwebview)

Then check this one out --> 
[Xcode UIWebView local HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654509/xcode-uiwebview-local-html)

Hopefully this works out for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"main-title\").value = \"New Title\""];
```

make sure you execute this code after the document is loaded.